# Delphi text parsing to a Crystal XI R2 report

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, vcl

I'm investigating the option of pushing translated text live to a crystal report. The problem I'm having is this:

I have a text object on my report with the following text:

> `From the date of {?FromDate} until the date of {?UntilDate}`.

Now when I retrieve the text with TCrpe I get the following "

> `From the date of  until the date of`

Now with TCrpe its possible to get the list of embedded objects using:

> `TCrpeTextObjectsItem.EmbeddedFields`

The problem is I have no Idea of how to identify at what position to insert these objects in my extracted text. The reason i need to know this position is so that when the translated text is sent back to me, I know what position to push these embedded objects back into, when parsing the translation to the report.

The second part of my problem will be that once I know the positions when pushing the translation to the report, how do I set the embedded object to use that position. However I'm hoping that solving the first issue will help me with the second.

Comment: Perhaps there are other properties that will pull the 'formula' from the text field instead of the current value?

Comment: Perhaps. I'll look into it. If I come up with a solution I'll post it.

Comment: Instead of working directly with the properties of TCrpeTextObjectItem, I found a procedure called PEGetText, which is part of the CrpeEngine. This is a call to the export procedure of the crpe32.dll. However the problem is there is a comment on this call specifically stating that: "Returned text include return and tab key. embedded fields are replaced by [].". Now that means the embedded fields are completely removed from the resultant text. So unfortunately I'm still having no luck.

Comment: For future reference to anyone trying to do the same, rather just avoid trying to change the embedded text fields, rather just convert all the embedded text fields to formula fields, and edit those instead.